# Finding a regex for an ID format with hyphens

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate an id using regex. The id is in the below format.

*alphaNumeric-alphaNumeric-alphaNumeric* (And the total length should be 14, and there should be two hyphens)

**Below examples are valid formats**

AS12-AS12-AB1C

AS-12ASBC-1234

N-IKNKL-A2LI40

Here the catch is hyphens should not come in the beginning as well as in the end. And also no two hyphens should be together.

Up until now I'm using positive look ahead to do the length match `(?=^.{14}$)`. And matching the other hyphens logic using `(?=^[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+`. So the regex I'm using is

```
(?=^.{12}$)(?=^[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+
```

And the problem here is hyphens can come in the beginning as well as at the end, as well as two hyphens can come together, both of which should not be valid and it's against my id validation check.

Comment: which language's regex engine are you using?

Comment: Or in other words, do you always need 2 hyphens in input?

Comment: Two hyphens are required. @anubhava

Comment: Language is Kotlin @hjpotter92, but does it matter? My knowledge in regex is minimal. So not sure if regex pattern matches based on language.

Comment: some languages have a restrictive regex engine. Try `(?=^.{14})^\w+-\w+-\w+$`

Comment: @hjpotter92: Your regex matches `___-___-___`

Comment: Is `ABCDEF--123456` valid? i.e. are alphanums mandatory between hyphens or not?

Comment: @Toto It's not valid. Two hyphens should not be together. The query is already answered. Please check the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
^(?=.{14}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+){2}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o3STWe/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Match Start
- `(?=.{14}$)`: Lookahead condition to assert that we have exact 14 characters of input
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`: Match 1 or more of alphanumeric characters
- `(?:`: Start a non-capturing group

  - `-`: Match a hyphen
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`: Followed by 1 or more of alphanumeric characters
- `){2}`: End non-capturing group. Match 2 instances of this group
- `$`: Match end

Comment: Glad to know. You may use lookahead as `(?=.{14}$)` as well since we're anyway matching only alphanumerics and hyphen later.

Comment: If that's a better solution, can you please update the answer above

Comment: That's not really better but a bit shorter. Updating the answer.